# Hibernate Restrictions.in first result from the list not form DB

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I would like to change the order of the result. I don't want the first item found in the DB, but the first result on the list.

For exemple, my result of this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("name.id", listOfId))
```

when my DB is like:

---

### | ID | NAME  |

### | 1  | name1 |

### | 2  | name2 |

### | 3  | name3 |

### | 4  | name4 |

and my list: listOfId[4,2,3]

the result is "2" because is the first result of my DB "IN" my listOfId

I want the result to be 4. The first in the listOfId.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to reorder the result in Java. The SQL/Hibernate solution is quite complex. You essentially need something like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE name.id WHEN 4 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 3 THEN 3 ELSE NULL END
```

Since this requires a new SQL for every parameter combination, this will perform badly. So it's best if you do this reordering in Java.